# Are multiple queries submitted to MongoDB carried out in parallel or serial?

Tags: mongodb, parallel-processing

Theoretical scenarios:

I submit a query and then in 5 minutes I would like to submit a second query in parallel.

I submit 5 queries at the same time and they are not related whatsoever.

Will MongoDB carry these out in parallel? I have a many-core server and would like to know if it is possible to do such parallelization

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it definitely runs simultaneous commands in parallel.

From the official documentation http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+does+concurrency+work :

> The mongod process uses a modified reader/writer lock with dynamic yielding on page faults and long operations. Any number of concurrent read operations are allowed, but a write operation can block all other operations.

You can also scale (run in parallel) inserts and updates via sharding, where the write operations are spread across many servers. More here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Introduction

Comment: Yes, upon further thought it would never make sense for any such software to do this serially on a server with potentially high amounts of traffic

Comment: Does MongDB also execute read queries on shards in parallel? Meaning if there is no shard key specified, will mongos spread the scatter and gather queries concurrently or sequentially?

Answer (score -6):

Mongodb is a scalable, high-performance NoSql ( here, there is no tables. Only "objects" which are formed with "documents" ( chunks of data ) ).

Yes,I think it runs queries in parallel but you have a multicore cpu not ensures the database runs better or faster.

Depends on compiled version. For example, the 32 bits version shares well known issues with x32 software.

Also, it depends how was developed ( with / without multicore support ).

Furthermore, read official documentation. 
http://www.mongodb.org/

It's more precise than my memory xD